# sparse matrices with GSL - compilation error

Tags: compilation, sparse-matrix, gsl

I'm testing out the GNU Scientific Library (GSL) and I want to create a sparse matrix with it. This is my code which directly comes from https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Sparse-Matrix-Examples.html:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <gsl/gsl_spmatrix.h>

int
main()
{
    gsl_spmatrix *A = gsl_spmatrix_alloc(5, 4); /* triplet format */
    gsl_spmatrix *C;
    size_t i, j;

    /* build the sparse matrix */
    gsl_spmatrix_set(A, 0, 2, 3.1);
    gsl_spmatrix_set(A, 0, 3, 4.6);
    gsl_spmatrix_set(A, 1, 0, 1.0);
    gsl_spmatrix_set(A, 1, 2, 7.2);
    gsl_spmatrix_set(A, 3, 0, 2.1);
    gsl_spmatrix_set(A, 3, 1, 2.9);
    gsl_spmatrix_set(A, 3, 3, 8.5);
    gsl_spmatrix_set(A, 4, 0, 4.1);

    printf("printing all matrix elements:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
           printf("A(%zu,%zu) = %g\n", i, j,
           gsl_spmatrix_get(A, i, j));

    /* print out elements in triplet format */
    printf("matrix in triplet format (i,j,Aij):\n");
    for (i = 0; i < A->nz; ++i)
         printf("(%zu, %zu, %.1f)\n", A->i[i], A->p[i], A->data[i]);

    /* convert to compressed column format */
    C = gsl_spmatrix_compcol(A);

    printf("matrix in compressed column format:\n");
    printf("i = [ ");
    for (i = 0; i < C->nz; ++i)
        printf("%zu, ", C->i[i]);
    printf("]\n");

    printf("p = [ ");
    for (i = 0; i < C->size2 + 1; ++i)
         printf("%zu, ", C->p[i]);
    printf("]\n");

    printf("d = [ ");
    for (i = 0; i < C->nz; ++i)
         printf("%g, ", C->data[i]);
    printf("]\n");

    gsl_spmatrix_free(A);
    gsl_spmatrix_free(C);

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled this code using the following command:

```
 gcc test1.c -o test -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

The result was:

```
 /tmp/ccyBfp0p.o: In function `main':
 test1.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `gsl_spmatrix_alloc'
 test1.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `gsl_spmatrix_set'
 test1.c:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `gsl_spmatrix_set'
 test1.c:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `gsl_spmatrix_set'
 test1.c:(.text+0xb0): undefined reference to `gsl_spmatrix_set'
 test1.c:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `gsl_spmatrix_set'
 /tmp/ccyBfp0p.o:test1.c:(.text+0x102): more undefined references to    `gsl_spmatrix_set' follow
 /tmp/ccyBfp0p.o: In function `main':
 test1.c:(.text+0x189): undefined reference to `gsl_spmatrix_get'
 test1.c:(.text+0x25d): undefined reference to `gsl_spmatrix_compcol'
 test1.c:(.text+0x39b): undefined reference to `gsl_spmatrix_free'
 test1.c:(.text+0x3a7): undefined reference to `gsl_spmatrix_free'
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then I tried to use the following code to compile:

```
 gcc -I/usr/local/include/gsl -L/usr/local/lib -o test test1.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

This compiled the code without error but when I tried to run it the following error occurred:

```
 ./test: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.19: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But when I do:

```
 ls /usr/local/lib
```

I can see the result:

```
 libemon.a       libgslcblas.so        libgsl.so         python2.7
 libgsl.a        libgslcblas.so.0      libgsl.so.19      python3.4
 libgslcblas.a   libgslcblas.so.0.0.0  libgsl.so.19.1.0  site_ruby
 libgslcblas.la  libgsl.la             pkgconfig
```

I think I have a problem with my GSL installation. But the problem is, all other calculations work fine! Only the sparse matrix gives me this problem.

Comment: Are you sure that your installed version of GSL supports sparse arrays? What version of GSL are you using? (use the macros `GSL_VERSION`, `GSL_MAJOR_VERSION` and `GSL_MINOR_VERSION`)

Answer (score 1):

Does updating `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as follows fix the `error while loading shared libraries`?

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`